# Was SO RSS feed blocked for robots recently? (2024-02)

Tags: support, rss, cloudflare

Example: [https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/{user_id}](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/%7Buser_id%7D)

When going to my feed (https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/2391795), it works well.
But, since a few days, my GitHub Action that used to fetch that feed to generate my "Blog posts" on GitHub has been failing.
https://github.com/Vadorequest/Vadorequest#blogs-posts

I wonder if a recent change in SO feeds configuration is causing this behavior, it has been working for years.

[image]

```
Error: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/2391795 runner failed, please verify the configuration. Error:
Error: Looks like your website returned 403, There is nothing blog post workflow can do to fix it. Please check your website's RSS feed generation source code. Also double check the URL.
```

Comment: They cut over to Cloudflare and that causes issues for non-human readers in particular: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloudflare?tab=Newest the 403 is the response from Cloudflare when their service can't determine if the client requesting content is a bot or not. You would expect it assumes for RSS feeds endpoints that this always is non-human actor, but here we are.